# Datetime with postgresql, python, and a stored procedure

Tags: python, postgresql, stored-procedures, psycopg2

I have a stored procedure that contains this line:

`EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT * FROM stores.paint WHERE created >= %s...` where %s is filled in by a parameter: `dt TIMESTAMP`.

I am calling this from the python console:

`conn = psycopg2.connect(host=host, database=db, user=user, password=pass)
 r = conn.cursor()
 r.callproc('procedure_name', [datetime.datetime.now()])`

I get an error due to the space in the datetime / timestamp:

`psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "15"
 LINE 1: ...* FROM stores.paint WHERE created >= 2015-02-21 15:20:40.2...
                                                            ^`

I have tried using single quotes in the stored procedure.  This results in it using a literal `%s` in the query string.

So, how can I pass a parameter to a stored procedure that has a space in it, so that the query actually works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the string with single quotes to make it proper SQL:

```
FORMAT('... created >= ''%s'' ...')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `%L` instead of `%s` as placeholder in the PostgreSQL `format()` function. Read the docs.

```
EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT * FROM stores.paint WHERE created >= %L', dt);
```

Even better don't fill the placeholder value in `format()` but use `EXECUTE ... USING`

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM stores.paint WHERE created >= $1' USING dt;
```

Comment: The second example (a parameterized query) is a better choice, +1